# Deleting items from an array causes Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, json

I have a few jQuery plugins that I made - all parse JSON feeds and render them using Mustache.js; each plugin takes an integer value of how many items to display.

I received a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'link' of undefined` when trying to parse the Stack Overflow JSON feed with the following code:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: query,
      contentType: "jsonp",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function (jsonp) {

        /* loop through JSON items converting the time from UNIX timestamp
         ** format to readable words by parsing it through timeConverter() */
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < jsonp.items.length; i++) {
          if (i > num-1){
            delete jsonp.items[i];
          } else {
            jsonp.items[i].creation_date = timeConverter(jsonp.items[i].creation_date);
          }
        }


        var output = Mustache.render(must_template, jsonp);
        element.html(output);
        return element;
      } //EOF CALLBACK
    }); //EOF AJAX
```

As a quickfix I disabled the truncation by simply commenting out the `delete` operation.  The error suggests that Mustache.js is trying to access part of the JSON object which no longer exists; yet the `delete` operation clearly only affects items which are above the user-defined limit.

**When this behaviour occured there were still 20 items in the array.**

**Note:**
*Yes, I've answered this question myself; however - I'm more than willing to accept another answer if it shows best practice, a neater way or improves upon my answer in some way. :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` is a "lower-level" operator compared to arrays. It directly removes the *object property*, bypassing all the specific array logic and hence does not update the length of the array.

If you want to delete an element from an array, use either [`.splice` <sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), or in your case you can simply set the length of the array and iterate over the remaining elements *afterwards*:

```
jsonp.items.length = Math.min(num, jsonp.items.length);
for (i = 0; i < jsonp.items.length; i++) {
  jsonp.items[i].creation_date = timeConverter(jsonp.items[i].creation_date);
}
```

Comment: What would occur if a user specified a limit of 20, and the feed only returned 5 posts? ;)

Comment: Hey, I don't know what your code is doing ;) But you can always do `jsonp.items.length = Math.min(num, jsonp.items.length);` (updated answer) or guard the assignment with an `if(...)`.

Comment: haha, I'll admit the loop isn't well suited for resizing the array - it just made it nice and easy for me convert an object found in each item!

Answer (score 1):

After much googling I couldn't find anything, even StackOverflow had failed me. Then, by chance, I came across this unintended side-effect of my *'quick hack'* of commenting out the delete line..

[image: http://i50.tinypic.com/2ecgnxz.png]

Due to the fact I hadn't commented out the whole `if/else` block, my `timeConverter()` function wasn't being ran on the items which would ordinarily be deleted. This confirmed that the combination of `for()` and `if(){} / else{}` were working correctly. So it appeared as though Mustache.js was trying to access items that were already deleted! Almost as if the `length` property of the `items[]` array wasn't being updated when items were being deleted.

I made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Z54Wy/2/) test case and this confirmed it was the issue. Here's the code and ouput:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: query,
      contentType: "jsonp",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function (jsonp) {

        /* loop through JSON items converting the time from UNIX timestamp
         ** format to readable words by parsing it through timeConverter() */
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < jsonp.items.length; i++) {
          if (i > num-1){
              console.log("Deleting item. Current Count: "+jsonp.items.length);
            delete jsonp.items[i];
              console.log("Deleting item. New Count: "+jsonp.items.length);
          } else {
            jsonp.items[i].creation_date = timeConverter(jsonp.items[i].creation_date);
          }
        }
        console.log(jsonp);
        return element;
      } //EOF CALLBACK
    }); //EOF AJAX
```

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/546kgj.png]

I tried a quick fix of using a counter to count each deletion, and then subtracting the deletion counter from the `length` property ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Z54Wy/2/)):

```
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: query,
          contentType: "jsonp",
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function (jsonp) {

            /* loop through JSON items converting the time from UNIX timestamp
             ** format to readable words by parsing it through timeConverter() */
            var i, deleted = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < jsonp.items.length; i++) {
              if (i > num-1){
                delete jsonp.items[i];
                deleted++;
              } else {
                jsonp.items[i].creation_date = timeConverter(jsonp.items[i].creation_date);
              }
            }
            jsonp.items.length -= deleted;
            console.log(jsonp);
            return element;
          } //EOF CALLBACK
        }); //EOF AJAX
```

Here was the output this generated:

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/vg69vo.png]

This code then ran fine when placed back in to the test environment and utilised with Mustache.js. **Using the delete keyword doesn't affect the length property when used on an array**

Coming from a Java background I'd taken for granted the fact that `length` is a property, and not a function - and therefore it isn't nessacerily updated upon any changes being made to the array. A stupid mistake that cost me more time than it should've! However, I couldn't find any other posts regarding this so I thought I'd post it up in the hope it can help anyone else in a similar position!

Answer (score 1):

Delete is not changing array count as you already found out, it's only removing key. To remove items from array you can use splice. Example:

```
var array2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
array2.splice(2, 1);

console.log('---------------------------');
console.log(array2.length); // 3
console.log(array2[0]); // 1
console.log(array2[1]); // 2
console.log(array2[2]); // 4
console.log(array2[3]); // undefined
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/qbXjp/1/